# Can't "Run" iOS build in Trigger.IO

Tags: trigger.io

When I go to "Run" my build for iOS, I get this error.

`[INFO]     lldb.target.Launch(lldb.SBLaunchInfo(shlex.split(args[1] and args[1] or '')), error)
[INFO] IndexError: list index out of range`

I have seen [an issue](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy/issues/240) around this in PhoneGap's repo... but not sure how to fix this in Trigger.IO.

Comment: this seems to be resolved by upgrading from version `1.4.5` to `1.4.6`, but Trigger Toolkit warns me not to use `1.4.6` because `1.4.5` is the latest stable release...

Comment: This happened because I updated to XCode 8, which apparently does bad things to `1.4.5`

Comment: I had the same issue and it has disappeared after I upgrade platform to the latest 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Xcode 8.1. I had a similar issue. Running the command below solved my problem.

```
    npm install -g ios-deploy
```